# How to see significance of non-singular matrices in an exercise in group theory context to show that if $AB≠BA$, then $A2B2≠(AB)2.$

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Find $2\times2$ non-singular matrices $A, B$ where $AB\ne BA$. Show also that $A^2B^2 \ne (AB)^2$.

This question is given as an optional exercise (stated in the Preface to be not needed in a first course on Groups) in context of Group Theory. But, cannot see the significance of that property (non-singular matrices) for this question.

I mean that cannot see any significance of non-singular condition, in the context of groups' property of having inverse of each element in the set, w.r.t. the operation (here, matrix multiplication). For example, let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 3 \\
2 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 2 \\
1 & 5
\end{pmatrix},$$
so that
$$AB=
\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 3 \\
2 & 5
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 2 \\
1 & 5
\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}
-15 & 27 \\
-1 & 29
\end{pmatrix},$$
and
$$BA=
\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 2 \\
1 & 5
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
6 & 3 \\
2 & 5
\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}
-14 & 1 \\
16 & 28
\end{pmatrix}
.$$

Now
$$(AB)^2=
\begin{pmatrix}
-15 & 27 \\
-1 & 29
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
-15 & 27 \\
-1 & 29
\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}
198 & -14 \\
378 & 814
\end{pmatrix},$$
and

$$A^2B^2=
\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 3 \\
2 & 5
\end{pmatrix}^2 \times \begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 2\\
1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}^2=  \begin{pmatrix}
42 & 22\\
33 & 21
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}
11 & 4\\
2 & 27
\end{pmatrix}=  \begin{pmatrix}
506 & 762\\
405 & 699
\end{pmatrix}.$$

[image]

Comment: The non-singular matrices form a (non-abelian) group, if you allow singulars then inverses won't exist. So in the group theory context, it makes sense as it is formulated.

Comment: @nicky-hekster What about converting your comment to an answer?

Comment: @NickyHekster Then why this exercise of forming matrix multiplications, better a reference would be enough to the fact that matrix multiplication is non-commutative, in general.

Comment: @NickyHekster The answer by Servaes has helped me understand your comment.

Comment: @jiten, the answer of Servaes - this is was I meant.

Comment: @jiten Now you have my downvote; please choose a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of group theory it makes sense to require the matrices to be invertible, because the set of *invertible* $2\times2$-matrices forms a group under multiplication.

That said, the proof of the second part is much easier for invertible matrices; in this case
$$A^2B^2=(AB)^2=ABAB\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad AB=BA,$$
simply by multiplying by $A^{-1}$ from the left and by $B^{-1}$ from the right.

In fact, the second part is not necessarily true if $A$ and $B$ are not required to be invertible; for
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},$$
you have $AB\neq BA$ but $A^2B^2=(AB)^2$.

Comment: So, had the equality been there between $A^2B^2 = (AB)^2$, then matrix multiplication would have been shown commutative, i.e. $AB = BA$. Just need to check for the singularity condition. So, this argument shows link between invertibility of matrices and the inverse property needed for group formed by matrix multiplication on square matrices of any size (here, $2*2$).

Comment: If I tell what is the answer in the title, then there are two side-effects- (i) why I asked the question in the first place, (ii) down-voting because of (i). I have been down-voted (had earlier one vote) because of title edit. Please let it remain as the old one, now restored.

Comment: @jiten Now you have my downvote; please choose a more descriptive title.

Comment: Please remove your negative vote as have edited the title.

Comment: Please accede to my last request. It hurts when score goes down.